# How to handle multiple routers in react

Tags: reactjs

Let say we have a web application. It has usually many views, like index page, admin panel, help page, contact etc. I handle them using react-router-dom in the main index.js and it just works fine.

However now I faced problem with developing admin panel. It is one of the routes supported by the index.js router, but it contains its own menu with all actions available for admin.

How should I handle this, to only replace the content I need in the admin panel (admin actions menu stays), but not the whole content as I do from index.js router?

I tried to use the  in the admin panel place for content replacement, but it either says too much recursion (If I duplicated the route for admin panel itself) or simply does not work saying nothing.

I'm react newbie and I don't even know how to call this problem.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: It would be best if you could demonstrate your problem with short example.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you can do that by nesting routes. Example assuming you use react-router 4.x.x: render Router or BrowserRouter etc. component (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router) once, at the top level, and then nest Route components. In your case you have main router in your index.js, so probably something like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Route path="/" exact component={Main} />
   <Route path="/some-page" component={SomePage} />
   <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

then, in your `Admin` component you don't create another Router, instead just render Routes again, so something like this:

```
<div className="admin-panel-container">
  <AdminMenu />
  <Route path="/admin/users" component={AdminUsers} />
  <Route path="/admin/groups" component={AdminGroups} />
</div>
```

so when URL matches `/admin` you'll see `AdminMenu` and component for a specific view in admin panel. You probably want to redirect from /admin to /admin/users or some dashboard, that depends on your specific application.

Now, if you have some layout elements surrounding your main router that you want to get rid of in admin routes, it's hard to say more without seeing some code example, but I guess you could create two components, for example, Layout and AdminLayout, each containing menus, header etc. and accepting children, and use them in every route depending on if it's admin or regular user route.

Comment: @simka Is there any reference or docs about that BrowserRouter need to be used only once? It was hard for me to find it except only this answer and I personally think this part should be documented

Comment: this last paragraph is the most important one and it is not clearly explained

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me with react-router-dom 6.2.1 was the following:

1. For the main page router, in index.js (or App.js), **a `*` character needed to be added after admin/**:

   ```
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" exact element={<Main />} />
            <Route path="/some-page" element={<SomePage />} />
            <Route path="/admin/*" element={<Admin />} />
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
   ```
2. For its navigation bar:

   ```
    <div className="links">
        <Link to="/">Main</Link>
        <Link to="/some-page">Some Page</Link>
        <Link to="/admin">Admin Page</Link>
    </div>
   ```
3. For the admin page router, **the admin/ part of the path must not be repeated**:

   ```
    <div className="admin-panel-container">
        <AdminMenu />
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/users" element={<AdminUsers />} />
            <Route path="/groups" element={<AdminGroups />} />
        </Routes>
    </div>
   ```
4. But in the admin navigation bar,  **the path must contain the admin/ part** :

   ```
    <div className="admin-links">
        <Link to="/admin/users">Explore Users</Link>
        <Link to="/admin/groups">Explore Groups</Link>
    </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In App you need to register like below

```
<BrowserRouter>
     <Routes>
         <Route path="/" exact element={<Main />} />
         <Route path="/admin/*" element={<Admin />} />
     </Routes>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

and inside the Admin page, wherever you need to render page content you just need to use

```
              <Routes>
                <Route
                  path="/your-path"
                  element={
                    <YourComponent />
                  }
                />
              </Routes>
```