# Why aren't components being rendered according to route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-redux

I'm using react router and I have created a route with the path `/account` which renders the Account component. That component renders a navbar. Below that navbar I want it to render a different component depending on what the URL is. If the URL is `account/edit` I want to show the edit account component, if the URL is `account/myorders` I want it to show my orders component and lastly if the URL is `account/favorites` I want it to show the favorites component below my navbar,

- Edit Account
- My Orders
- Favorites

Now I have this problem that the url changes but no component renders below my navbar. if I use exact path on the `/account` route I get "*path does not exist*" on  the routes `/edit`, `/myorders` and `/favorites`. if I don't use exact on the `/account` route the same view shows on all routes. Only time when I get a component to render is if I change the route on for example `/edit` to `/`.

```
function Routes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />

      <Route path="/account" component={Account} />

      <Route render={() => <Route component={Error} />} />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

These are my already existing routes that works that are imported into my App.js component

```
const Account = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/edit" component={EditAccount} exact />
        <Route path="/myorders" component={MyOrders} />
        <Route path="/favorites" component={Favorites} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

These are the routes in my Account.js component that does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The soloution for me was to use nested routes like this.

```
const Account = () => {
  let match = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar />
      <h1>Account</h1>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${match.path}/edit`} component={EditAccount} exact />
        <Route path={`${match.path}/myorders`} component={MyOrders} />
        <Route path={`${match.path}/favorites`} component={Favorites} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the fact that you are using `<Router></Router>` to wrap your `routes` inside the `Acouunt` component.

Try to remove that, something like this :-

```
const Account = () => {
  return (
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/edit" component={EditAccount} exact />
        <Route path="/myorders" component={MyOrders} />
        <Route path="/favorites" component={Favorites} />
      </Switch>
  );
};
```

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473727/how-to-handle-multiple-routers-in-react) for more info.

Comment: That did not work for me, but I found a solution. It was to use nested routes.